# Correct CRS / projection for LAS LiDAR point cloud data from USGS

Tags: coordinate-system, qgis-3

I am getting LiDAR LPC data in LAZ format from https://apps.nationalmap.gov/downloader/ and can successfully open it in QGIS.  I am been using EPSG:32617 based on the AOI location.

I save the LAZ data out as an ESRI Shapefile into EPSG:32617, and then convert to DEM from that.

I'd like to add a Google basemap.

What CRS / Projection should I be using to allow me to see the base map and the point cloud data together in the right place?

I noticed that the TIN interpolation on the shapefile takes a long time (maybe having to re-project on the fly, or is it the 490K points?), so maybe there is a better workflow to include more appropriate CRS and/or Projection?  Is that even relevant to my basic question, or just me guessing as I learn more?

[image: USGS Point Cloud LiDAR data from here]

Comment: You can click on the Info/Metadata to get coordinate system and other information.  I would think it would be in a Nad 83 datum and not WGS but you will find the answer in the metadata.

Comment: Unfortunately the LAZ files come in with no projection assigned, so I am trying to figure which I should use so that a google base map can coexist with this data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Metadata XML for that file shows this:

Lambert Conformal Conic

stdparll:
40.43333333333333

stdparll:
41.7

longcm: -82.5

latprjo: 39.66666666666666

feast: 1968500.0

fnorth: 0.0

GCS North American 1983

GRS 1980

semiaxis: 6378137.0

denflat: 298.257222101

North American Vertical Datum of 1988

foot us

The parameters in the Metadata XML agree with [EPSG:3734](https://epsg.io/3734)

[image]

Comment: Thank you, so you read the XML metadata starting with the <mapproj> key, and I see what you have posted within the xml.

How did you derive that EPSG:3734 is the one based on the xml metadata?

Comment: I searched Ohio North in the https://epsg.io/ site and EPSG:3734 matched all the parameters. It would have been nice if they had put coordinate system information in the header of the LAZ file, or explicitly called out the EPSG number in the XML. Usually they do.

Comment: I was able to compare 4 key values in the XML metadata to the Ohio North entries at  https://epsg.io/ and saw how you matched it.  There's no "easy" way - you just have to manually read the entries looking for key => value matches from the XML metadata.  I found those in the"Attributes":


Unit: US survey foot
Geodetic CRS: NAD83
Datum: North American Datum 1983
Ellipsoid: GRS 1980  


Thank you for the answer and the lesson.